# ROLLUP BY year,week

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I am trying to use the ROLLUP command to group my data by year/week, customer_id but I can't seem to get it to work.

Below is my sample data and my attempt. Can someone show me how to make this work

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS.FF';

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE customers 
(CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Faith', 'Mazzarone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Saladino' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Micheal', 'Palmice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Jerry', 'Torchiano' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE items 
(PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Black Shoes', 79.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Brown Pants', 111.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'White Shirt', 10.99 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE purchases
(CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PURCHASE_DATE) AS
SELECT 1, 101, 3, TIMESTAMP'2022-10-11 09:54:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 100, 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-10-12 19:04:18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 101,1, TIMESTAMP '2022-10-11 09:54:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 101, 3, TIMESTAMP '2022-10-17 19:34:58' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 102, 3,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-06 11:41:25' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM  dual CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 101,1, TIMESTAMP '2022-12-11 09:54:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 102,1, TIMESTAMP '2022-12-17 19:04:18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-12 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 5;

SELECT 
      p.customer_id,
      c.first_name,
      c.last_name,
      sum(p.quantity * i.price) total_amt 
       FROM purchases p,
            items i,
            customers c
 WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id 
 GROUP BY ROLLUP    (to_char(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW'),(p.customer_id)));
```

Comment: You should group either by `TRUNC(p.purchase_date, 'IW')` or `to_char(p.purchase_date, 'IYYY/IW')`. Otherwise the group is not 100% correct when week belongs to privious/next year.

Comment: And you should turn to modern ANSI join syntax, which exists for at least 20 years. You selected three tables but provided only one join condition, i.e. for `items` you do a **CROSS JOIN**, I don't think this is by intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included a `JOIN` condition for the `items` table and, since the `first_name` and `last_name` are dependent on the `customer_id` then, you can aggregate the name components:

```sql
SELECT p.customer_id,
       CASE
       WHEN p.customer_id IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX(c.first_name)
       END AS first_name,
       CASE
       WHEN p.customer_id IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX(c.last_name)
       END AS last_name,
       to_char(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW') AS week,
       sum(p.quantity * i.price) total_amt 
FROM   purchases p
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
       INNER JOIN items i
       ON p.product_id = i.product_id
GROUP BY
       ROLLUP(
         p.customer_id,
         to_char(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW')
       );
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | WEEK | TOTAL_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Faith | Mazzarone | 2022/41 | 415.96 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/41 | 111.99 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/42 | 335.97 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/49 | 65.94 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/50 | 131.88 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/49 | 111.99 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/50 | 142.87 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/51 | 87.92 |
| 1 | Faith | Mazzarone | *null* | 415.96 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | *null* | 645.78 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | *null* | 342.78 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1404.52 |

and reversing the `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT p.customer_id,
       CASE
       WHEN p.customer_id IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX(c.first_name)
       END AS first_name,
       CASE
       WHEN p.customer_id IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX(c.last_name)
       END AS last_name,
       to_char(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW') AS week,
       sum(p.quantity * i.price) total_amt 
FROM   purchases p
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
       INNER JOIN items i
       ON p.product_id = i.product_id
GROUP BY
       ROLLUP(
         to_char(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW'),
         p.customer_id
       );
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | WEEK | TOTAL_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Faith | Mazzarone | 2022/41 | 415.96 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/41 | 111.99 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/42 | 335.97 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/49 | 65.94 |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2022/50 | 131.88 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/49 | 111.99 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/50 | 142.87 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022/51 | 87.92 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022/41 | 527.95 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022/42 | 335.97 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022/49 | 177.93 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022/50 | 274.75 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022/51 | 87.92 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1404.52 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7_g1_Kqd)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks as

```
SQL>   SELECT p.customer_id,
  2           c.first_name,
  3           c.last_name,
  4           TO_CHAR (p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW') year_week,
  5           SUM (p.quantity * i.price) total_amt
  6      FROM purchases p, items i, customers c
  7     WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id
  8  GROUP BY c.first_name,
  9           c.last_name,
 10           p.customer_id,
 11           ROLLUP (TO_CHAR (p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW'))
 12  ORDER BY customer_id, year_week;

CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_N LAST_NAME YEAR_WE  TOTAL_AMT
----------- ------- --------- ------- ----------
          1 Faith   Mazzarone 2022/41     811,88
          1 Faith   Mazzarone             811,88
          2 Lisa    Saladino  2022/41     202,97
          2 Lisa    Saladino  2022/42     608,91
          2 Lisa    Saladino  2022/49    1217,82
          2 Lisa    Saladino  2022/50    2435,64
          2 Lisa    Saladino             4465,34
          3 Micheal Palmice   2022/49     202,97
          3 Micheal Palmice   2022/50    2638,61
          3 Micheal Palmice   2022/51    1623,76
          3 Micheal Palmice              4465,34

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Fyi Wernfried response pointed something interesting out in case you want to take a look. Thanks for your help and expertise

Answer (score 1):

In general the two other answer are OK, however the `GROUP BY` is wrong.

Consider this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO PURCHASES  (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PURCHASE_DATE) 
SELECT 2, 102, 3,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-26 11:41:25' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM  dual CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 101,1, TIMESTAMP '2022-12-21 09:54:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 102,1, TIMESTAMP '2022-12-27 19:04:18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-22 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15;


SELECT p.customer_id,       
    TO_CHAR(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW') AS WEEK,
    SUM(p.quantity * i.price) total_amt 
FROM purchases p 
   JOIN customers c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
   JOIN items i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
GROUP BY ROLLUP(p.customer_id, TO_CHAR(p.purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW'))
ORDER BY 2;
```

returns

```
+-----------------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|WEEK   |TOTAL_AMT|
+-----------------------------+
|3          |2022/51|155.95   |
|2          |2022/52|65.94    |
|3          |2022/52|142.87   |
|3          |2023/01|131.88   |
|2          |2023/01|98.91    |
|3          |2023/02|175.84   |
|3          |2023/03|131.88   |
|2          |2023/52|32.97    |
|3          |2023/52|43.96    |
|2          |       |197.82   |
|3          |       |782.38   |
|           |       |980.2    |
+-----------------------------+
```

But I guess you are rather looking for this:

```
SELECT p.customer_id,       
    TO_CHAR(trunc(p.purchase_date, 'IW'), 'IYYY/IW') AS WEEK,
    SUM(p.quantity * i.price) total_amt 
FROM   purchases p 
JOIN customers c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN items i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
GROUP BY ROLLUP(p.customer_id, TRUNC(p.purchase_date, 'IW'))
ORDER BY 2;

+-----------------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|WEEK   |TOTAL_AMT|
+-----------------------------+
|3          |2022/51|155.95   |
|2          |2022/52|98.91    |
|3          |2022/52|186.83   |
|2          |2023/01|98.91    |
|3          |2023/01|131.88   |
|3          |2023/02|175.84   |
|3          |2023/03|131.88   |
|           |       |980.2    |
|3          |       |782.38   |
|2          |       |197.82   |
+-----------------------------+
```

See difference with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT       
    TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS purchase_date,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(purchase_date, 'IW'), 'IYYY-"W"IW') AS ISO_WEEK, 
    TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY/IW') AS WEEK
FROM purchases p 
ORDER BY purchase_date

+------------------------------+
|PURCHASE_DATE|ISO_WEEK|WEEK   |
+------------------------------+
|2022-12-21   |2022-W51|2022/51|
|2022-12-24   |2022-W51|2022/51|
|2022-12-26   |2022-W52|2022/52|
|2022-12-27   |2022-W52|2022/52|
|2022-12-28   |2022-W52|2022/52|
|2022-12-30   |2022-W52|2022/52|
|2023-01-01   |2022-W52|2023/52| <- Note the difference
|2023-01-03   |2023-W01|2023/01|
|2023-01-05   |2023-W01|2023/01|
|2023-01-07   |2023-W01|2023/01|
|2023-01-09   |2023-W02|2023/02|
|2023-01-11   |2023-W02|2023/02|
|2023-01-13   |2023-W02|2023/02|
|2023-01-15   |2023-W02|2023/02|
|2023-01-17   |2023-W03|2023/03|
|2023-01-19   |2023-W03|2023/03|
|2023-01-21   |2023-W03|2023/03|
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm looking for the total amount of purchases made by all customers for every week. In addition, I will generate similar queries to break down the data for every month and every year. Once I get this all figured out  I can compare them to other periods. Ie year 2021 W 50 to Year 2022 W 50. This will tell me gains or loses. Having said  that, which is the best way to proceed. Thanks in advance for your expertise and insight